# Windows 10 does not detect touchpad and touchscreen (not shown in device manager)

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, touchscreen

I just got a new HP laptop. After booting it up to make sure it worked and Windows was activated, I opened it up and replace the Optane m.2 with a 512 GB m.2 SSD, then I reformatted and reinstalled W10 on the SSD.

After booting the new W10 install for the first time, I immediately noticed that the touchpad was not working. However I continued with installing drivers and updates hoping that this would fix it. No luck. I've tried googling everything, but haven't found anything that works. Later I noticed that the touchscreen is the exact same. It does not work and is not detected by windows. I tried booting Ubuntu off of a USB stick and both the touchpad and touchscreen work perfectly there.

Specs:

- HP Pavilion x360 - 15t-dq100 CTO
- Core i5 10210U
- Windows 10 Home 64 bit (clean install, downloaded the installation iso from Microsoft and ran it off a USB stick)

Additional information and things I've tried:

- Touchpad and touchscreen do not show up in device manager, even with "Show Hidden Devices".
- Touchpad and touchscreen work fine in BIOS and Ubuntu live USB (not a hardware problem).
- USB mouse works fine.
- I have fully installed all Windows updates and checked that there are no more updates.
- I used HP's updater tool and it did not find anything to update.
- There are no touchpad or touchscreen drivers on HP's website for this laptop.
- I've tried installing Synaptics touchpad drivers from similar HP laptops, but it hasn't done anything (the files extract to a folder, then nothing seems to run).
- There are no touchpad or touchscreen settings in the BIOS (the only settings I didn't recognize were TPM settings, but after reading about that it's clearly unrelated).
- There is no touchpad toggle on this keyboard (at least none indicated).
- I tried going through the Control Panel > Devices > Add Device, but it does not detect the touchpad or touchscreen.

Maybe relevant:

Several of the drivers I downloaded from HP's website failed to install with the error: "This driver is not supported on this OS version (10.0.18363)." This included several Intel drivers (graphics, audio, and serial IO). However I used Intel's automatic driver updater, it was able to install new graphics and audio drivers. It didn't show the serial IO drivers, and I couldn't find them on Intel's website (a I found a bunch of serial IO drivers for NUCs, but this appears to be irrelevant to me?). After installing those Intel drivers, everything else is working fine.

I've been doing a lot of googling to find a solution to this problem, but nothing has worked. Most of the links I have found require that the device is already detected, so that drivers can be manually installed or reinstalled. However since the devices are not detected I cannot do this, and none of the touchpad or touchscreen settings show up in Windows because Windows does not believe the devices exist. But both devices work perfectly fine outside of Windows (in BIOS, in HP's UEFI diagnostic tool, and in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

tl;dr: I needed to find and install Intel Serial IO drivers.

Long version: I exchanged the laptop for the same model. I was more careful with the new laptop and made an image of the factory state so I could recover if it had the same problem. After reinstalling Windows, it did in fact still have the same problem and I restored the factory image. At this point I remembered the Serial IO drivers that wouldn't install on the laptop because the Windows version was too recent. Since I still had the working factory image I was able to check device manager for the names of the Serial IO devices. Googling these names I was able to find Lenovo drivers that successfully installed, and then later I found the up to date drivers on HP's FTP server (the drivers on the support page are still out of date). With these drivers the touchpad and touchscreen devices appeared and worked correctly.

The latest (as of this answer) drivers can be downloaded [here](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp99001-99500/sp99312.exe) ([readme](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp99001-99500/sp99312.html)). However this link is likely to become out of date in the future. You can try googling `site:ftp.hp.com intel serial io gpio host controller int34bb` to find the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

if you're installing windows 10 then you don't need to install any kind of driver it'll automatically update and install the driver and your pc should be connected to a good internet network to update and install the driver or you can do it manually like got to settings>update & security> click on check for updates. or you can follow the method shared by joey on to fix this touchpad error on [Get the touchpad driver](https://techocen.com/fix-hp-synaptics-touchpad-driver/) and official website of hp.com here's it: [Get the touchpad driver from official](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Synaptics-Touchpad-not-working/td-p/7537354)